# How to file nails for flamenco guitar?

Tags: guitar, flamenco

I have been growing out my nails and they are long enough now to where I can file them to the correct shape, but I am not sure how to file them? How would I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Oh boy, this is a can of worms.

I suggest trawling around youtube for advice. There is also the Delcamp classical guitar forum which has various long disussions about nails.

The best shape for the nails depends on so many factors that little general advice is possible. For most players it's a long process of experiment. If you're using standard flamenco hand-positions and have 'normal' nails, if there is such a thing,  then you'll want to do what most players do, and for this there is a lot of material online.

Comment: At the risk of starting a flame war, are fingerpicks a reasonable alternative?